# Keeping relative position while teleporting my player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a teleport system to allow my player and other objects between maps. When I enter a trigger I want to come out of the other portal at the relative position at which I entered the first (eg: if I were to go in from the left of the portal, I would exit from the left of the other one).

My code:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (!justTeleported.Contains(other.gameObject))
    {
        if (other.transform != null && other.transform.tag == "Player" || other.transform != null && other.transform.tag == "Ammo")
        {
            Vector3 velocity = other.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity;
            other.transform.position=connectedTo.transform.position;
            other.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = velocity;
            connectedTo.GetComponent<Portal>().justTeleported.Add(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

(My player can also pick up and throw objects into the portals)

Comment: `other.transform != null && other.transform.tag == "Player" || other.transform != null && other.transform.tag == "Ammo"` could be `other.transform != null && (other.transform.tag == "Player" || other.transform.tag == "Ammo")` (just saying)

Comment: What if from above the first teleporter looked like `|` and the second one like `_`? And what if the teleporters were face to face?

Comment: Since I'm using this strictly as a door system for teleporting between maps (eg: entering a house), I don't think I'll come across a situation where that'll be an issue.

Comment: You mean all of your portals are facing the same axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the relative position to the teleporter

```
var relative = player.transform.position - teleporter.transform.position;
```

Then when you teleport the player

```
player.transform.position = teleporterExit.transform.position + relative;
```

Comment: What if from above the first teleporter looked like `|` and the second one like `_`?

Comment: You mean, what if they are rotated differently? Take the rotation difference and apply it to the vector

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean. Then you would need to calculate the rotation between `teleporter` and `teleporterExit`